# Close word Add In From Inside Application

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins, word-web-addins

I have an Word Office Add-in built using Office.js library.The purpose of the add-in is to look for custom property set for word document and if its custom property is found it should perform a specific task or else if it doesn't find the custom property addin should close

Is there a way to close the add-in frame altogether from inside the application? i tried office.context.ui.closeContainer but i am getting null reference

***code****

```
function PropertyCheck() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var customDocProps = context.document.properties.customProperties;
            // first, load custom properties object
            context.load(customDocProps);
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    write(customDocProps.items.length);
                    // now load actual property
                    var filenameProp = customDocProps.getItemOrNullObject("Group");
                    context.load(filenameProp);
                    return context.sync()
                        .then(function () {
                            //write(filenameProp.value);
                            if (filenameProp.value == "Test") {
                                //logic
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                office.context.ui.closeContainer();
                            }
                        });
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Any update/help on this please? @Cindy Meister